# Testing Async Functions With Mocha

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mocha.js

I'm using MochaJS for tests of my NodeJS application.

I have a `someFunc()` function and that function is like that:

```
function someFunc(cb) {
    // Do some async works...
    // When async works finish
    if(err) // if there is error
        cb(err);
    else
        cb();
}
```

And testing it like this:

```
it('...', function(done) {
    className.someFunc(function(err) {
      if (err) done(err);
      else done();
    });
});
```

But I'm still getting this error:

```
Error: Timeout of 30000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

I'm using `done()` function inside a callback function. Is it a problem?

Comment: What you've got there should be fine. Are you sure `someFunc` is calling the callback?

Comment: @cartant yes, that's my exact problem. I need a coffee :) Thank you. Can you send it as answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

*Note* This is actaully @cartant's answer but he didn't send it as answer so I will explain the solution.

I couldn't realize it but in one of cases in `someFunc` , it's not calling the callback. So if you have same problem, be sure your function is really calling callback.